# Python not saving files to a different folder than where the python file is on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python, image, save, jpeg

So I am pulling jpg's from a url. I am able to save the image files as long as they are being saved to the same folder the python file is in. As soon as I attempt to change the folder(seen here as the outpath) the image files do not get created. I imagine it has something to do with my outpath, but it seems to be fine when I am printing and watching it in the console.

Ubuntu 11.10 OS by the way. I'm a newbie with both linux and python, so it could easily be either. :)

If I were to print the sequence taken from the CSV file it would look like: [['Champ1', 'Subname1', 'imgurl1'],['Champ2', 'subname2', 'imgurl2'],['Champ3','subname3','imgurl3']...]

(It was scraped from a website)

```
import csv
from urlparse import urlsplit
from urllib2 import urlopen, build_opener
from urllib import urlretrieve
import webbrowser
import os
import sys


reader = csv.reader(open('champdata.csv', "rb"), delimiter = ",", skipinitialspace=True)


champInfo = []


for champs in reader:
    champInfo.append(champs)


size = len(champInfo)

def GetImages(x, out_folder="/home/sean/Home/workspace/CP/images"):
    b=1
    size = len(champInfo)
    print size

    while b < size:
        temp_imgurls = x.pop(b)
        filename = os.path.basename(temp_imgurls[2])
        print filename
        outpath = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
        print outpath
        u = urlopen(temp_imgurls[2])
        localFile = open(outpath, 'wb')
        localFile.write(u.read())
        localFile.close()


        b+=1

GetImages(champInfo)
```

I understand it's quite crude, but it does work, only if I'm not attempting to change the save path.

Comment: Try to replace `temp_imgurls[2].split('sites/default/files/game_data/1.0.0.136/content/champion/icons/')[-1]` with `os.path.basename(temp_imgurls[2])`

Comment: That does neaten up my code quite a bit, but ultimately doesn't fix the problem. :\

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the complete image path everywhere

E:/../home/sean/Home/workspace/CD/images

Comment: There is no `E:` at `/home/`.

Comment: This is on ubuntu, so I think I am putting my entire path. For what it's worth, if I try editing the path to shorten it, python throws an error, so I feel like it is a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

def GetImages(x):

```
b=1
size = len(champInfo)
print size
while b < size:
    temp_imgurls = x.pop(b)
    filename = temp_imgurls[2]
    u = urlopen(temp_imgurls[2])
    localFile = open(filename, 'wb')
    localFile.write(u.read())
    localFile.close()
```

And this code will be save files in the same directory where script is.

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for. I can already save the files in the same directory, it's saving them elsewhere that is the problem. :)

Comment: show your output of ls -l /home/sean/Home/workspace/CD/images

Comment: It's completely empty after running the file even though the prints clearly show the loop functioning properly. :)

Comment: Man, I don see your files, I need to see permissions on this directory ))

Comment: I didn't see the -l sorry! Hmm, you may be onto something: http://imgur.com/PMZzR

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:**

I think the answer to your problem is just to add a check for the output directory existence, and create it if needed.  ie, add:

```
if not os.path.exists(out_folder):
    os.makedirs(out_folder)
```

to your existing code.

---

More generally , you could try something more like this:

```
import csv
from urllib2 import urlopen
import os
import sys

default_outfolder = "/home/sean/Home/workspace/CD/images"
# simple arg passing wihtout error checking
out_folder = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else default_outfolder

if not os.path.exists(out_folder):
    os.makedirs(out_folder)  # creates out_folder, including any required parent ones
else:
    if not os.path.isdir(out_folder):
        raise RuntimeError('output path must be a directory')

reader = csv.reader(open('champdata.csv', "rb"), delimiter = ",", skipinitialspace=True)

for champs in reader:
    img_url = champs[2]
    filename = os.path.basename(img_url)
    outpath = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
    print 'Downloading %s to %s' % (img_url, outpath)
    with open(outpath, 'wb') as f:
        u = urlopen(img_url)
        f.write(u.read())
```

The above code works for champdata.csv of the form `stuff,more_stuff,http://www.somesite.com.au/path/to/image.png`
but will need to be adapted if I have not understood the actual format of your incoming data.

Comment: Oh I know. I have a complete lack of experience and it's one of those learning as I go situations. Stackoverflow has been invaluable, this has been the only problem I've run into where I did find something close enough to help. 

I tried your solution and I'm getting: ValueError: unknown url type: imgUrl. I think it is because the csv that is being opening is formatted like so champs[[Champ1, SubName, imgurl],[Champ2, Subname, imgurl],...]. Part of why it was setup the way it is, is so I can get to the imgurl. That was the only way I knew how.

Comment: You might need to give a sample line of the csv file, so I can fix my solution.

I've assumed something like:
`stuff, more stuff, http://www.somedomain.com/path/to/image.png`

Comment: Sorry - must have missed your sample line.  Is the CSV file just a single line then?

Comment: No, it has multiple rows. As in when opening it in excel, you'll get 3 columns (Name, Subname, imgurl) and ~90 rows, each a unique name, subname, and imgurl

Comment: Also, I don't see how my code could give the error you report.  Did you mix my code with yours, or did you just run my code?